# What does "#Define BLABLABLA (1 << 2) mean?

Tags: c

I am reviewing some C code, and found  a header file full of defines of the style:

```
#define BLABLABLABLA (1 << 2)
#define XXXXXXXXXXXX (1 << 3)
#define YYYYYYYYYYYY (1 << 4)
```

What do they mean? What do they do?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<< is the shift operator in C.
So you define BLABLABLABLABLA by a zero value with a binary 1 shifted by 2 digits to the left.

The resulting value is then :
...00000100

You would normally do this do mask things.
So, say you have one status byte where every bit is a flag.
And if the 3rd bit is set, this means BLABLABLABLABLA, you would do :

int blablaFlag = statusByte & BLABLABLABLABLA;

If this is greater 0, your flag was set.

Answer (score 3):

These defines can be used when storing information (flags) in bits:

```
#define HAS_SOMETHING (1 << 2)
#define HAS_ANOTHER (1 << 3)

int flags = 0;

if (has_something())
   flags |= HAS_SOMETHING;
if (has_another())
   flags |= HAS_ANOTHER;

// ... later:

if (flags & HAS_SOMETHING)
   do_something();
```

Using a <strike>macro</strike> preprocessor directive to set or unset these flags makes the code way more readable than this would:

```
if (flags & 4)   // 4 is 1 lsh 2
   do_something();
```

Answer (score 1):

They are a way of defining constants, using the C preprocessor.  So each time you use `XXXXXXXXXXXX` in your code it will be replaced with `1 << 2` by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` simply means that whenever `BLABLABLABLA` is seen, it's replaced with `(1 << 2)`.
So if you write `int x=BLABLABLABLA;`, it's as if you wrote `int x=(1 << 2);`.
`<<` is the shift left operator.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` and `>>` are *shift* operators, they work on a binary scale.

42 is written 42 in decimal and 101010 in binary.

When you use the operators :

```
          The binary representation of 42 is :        101010
42 << 1 : 101010 is "shifted" to the left, becoming  1010100, thus 84.
42 >> 1 : 101010 is "shifted" to the right, becoming   10101, thus 21.
```

This is used for flags for readability purposes : It's easier to read `1 << 1`, `1 << 2`, `1 << 3` than `1`, `2`, `4`.